# Print PDF File using Print.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, printjs

I'm having difficulties to show print modal passing a pdf file.

```
    setTimeout(() => {            
        printJS({
        printable: '53544.pdf',
        type: 'pdf',
        showModal: true,    
        fallbackPrintable: () => console.log("FallbackPrintable"),      
        onPrintDialogClose: () => console.log('The print dialog was closed'),
        onIncompatibleBrowser: () => console.log('Pdf was opened in a new tab due to an incompatible browser')
        })
        console.log("TimeOut Executado");
        }
        ,3000)
```

It is happing just with **pdf files**, I tested with image like `logo.png` and it worked. I insert that params to callback to trying to figured out what is happing, and `OnPrintDialogClose()` is trigged, but the modal box did not show! The screen blink and this message is showed `'The print dialog was closed'`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: In case you didn't know, a **lot** of people do **not** use the in-browser PDF-renderer, instead downloading the files and using Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Reader. In those cases, **which are beyond the control of the web application or JavaScript**, there is no way to access/force the print dialog.

Comment: it is a functionality in which the user print a "receipt". I didnt like the browser pdf render idea, I would like that print function to occur in background... but I think that it would  be necessary a API to comunicate with printer driver right?

Comment: Exactly! There are point-of-sale/invoicing systems which either communicate directly to the printer (requires configuring printer & router appropriately) or that use a special printer driver that grabs the web data and sends it to the local printer - which requires installing software on the client machine *outside the browser*. AFAIK (and I've looked a bit in years past) there is, **by design**, no way to force printing from a web application without additional hardware and/or out-of-browser-software.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://printjs.crabbly.com/#configuration I see there are some more configuration options that might give you clues.  I would recommend trying this (I added onError and modalMessage):

```
setTimeout(() => {            
  printJS({
    printable: '53544.pdf',
    type: 'pdf',
    showModal: true, 
    modalMessage: "Document Loading...",
    onError: (err) => console.log(err),
    fallbackPrintable: () => console.log("FallbackPrintable"),      
    onPrintDialogClose: () => console.log('The print dialog was closed')
  });
  console.log("TimeOut Executado");
  }, 3000)
```

Then my troubleshooting questions would be:

- If you look at the url of that page, appending /53544.pdf the right location?
- If you look in the network tab of your developer tools do you see the pdf being requested and is it successful?

Comment: I  forgot to mention, the address is localhost:3500, when the setTimout is loaded if I insert /53544.pdf it does not open, but if I open a new tab and write localhost:3500/53544.pdf, works!  About the location, I have at same folder an image and using it for testing, it worked!

Comment: I did that test `onError`, nothing trigged! and the network tab, the pdf file is being requested

Comment: Another test: what about a different pdf? The Print.js documentation link has sample PDFs. Maybe printjs can't handle the encoding of your pdf.